# How can I check indices.memory.index_buffer_size parameter is effectively working in elasticsearch?

Tags: memory, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch cluster, and I add indices.memory.index_buffer_size parameter in elasticsearch.yml file. 
   I set this parameter be 70%. And then the cluster began to indexing. After all, I reset this parameter be 10%, and I restart the elasticsearch.

My question is how can I check my settings are working?

Answer (score 3):

I think (but I'm not positive) that it should show up in the nodes information API.  Try this:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes?clear&all"
```

Comment: Default values will not show up. Use the "pretty" flag to make this easier to read. (curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes?clear&all&pretty")

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /_nodes API, but what I found puzzling was that the value for the setting is not returned if you are using the default. But once you change it (in elasticsearch.yml) and rebounce your cluster, it >will< appar in the output of the /_nodes API call.

to illustrate.

- install elastic search and start cluster.
- curl 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes'  | grep index_buffer_size # no match
- change value of index_buffer_size to other than default and bounce cluster
- curl 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes'  | grep index_buffer_size # Match !

My guess is that this is the case for any .yml setting, not just this one (although i have not verified that theory).

Comment: I think your guess about the values in .yml is correct. I have seen similar behaviour.